# Java text analysis program

Tags: java

The following requisites are those for the program I'm currently having an issue with:

The program must be able to open any text file specified by the user, and analyze the frequency of verbal ticks in the text. Since there are many different kinds of verbal ticks (such as "like", "uh", "um", "you know", etc) the program must ask the user what ticks to look for. A user can enter multiple ticks, separated by commas.

The program should output:

```
the total number of tics found in the text
the density of tics (proportion of all words in the text that are tics)
the frequency of each of the verbal tics
the percentage that each tic represents out of all the total number of tics
```

My program is working very well, but what I basically need to do is that I must use separate methods for each component of the analysis. So I think the idea is that I need to split up the program in a few parts, which I have done by using the comments `//` because I'm basically having problems determining which type I should return, I know the last part (`// public static void output(){`) 
should definitely be `void` because it returns nothing and only prints out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    double totalwords = 0; // double so density (totalwords/totalticks) returned can be double 
    int totalticks = 0;

    System.out.println("What file would you like to open?");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String files = sc.nextLine();    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(files));

    // public static int[] initialise()
    System.out.println("What words would you like to search for? (please separate with a comma)");
    String ticks = sc.nextLine();
    ticks = ticks.toLowerCase();
    String[] keys = ticks.split(","); 
    int[] values = new int[keys.length];


    // public static int[] processing(){?
    for (int z=0; z<keys.length; z++){
        values[z] = 0;
    }

    while (input.hasNext()){
        String next = input.next();
        totalwords++;
        for (int x = 0; x<keys.length; x++){
            if (next.toLowerCase().equals(keys[x])){
                values[x]+=1;        
            }
        }            
    }

    for (Integer u : values) {
        totalticks += u;
    }

    //public static void output(){
    System.out.println("Total number of tics :"+totalticks);
    System.out.printf("Density of tics (in percent): %.2f \n", ((totalticks/totalwords)*100));

    System.out.println(".........Tick Breakdown.......");

    for (int z = 0; z<keys.length; z++){
        System.out.println(keys[z] + "      /  "+ values[z]+" occurences   /"  + (values[z]*100/totalticks) + "% of all tics");
    }
}
```

Essentially the problem I'm having is the scope of the variables because Eclipse (my IDE) no longer recognizes the variables within each method once I get them out of comments - I know I need to use some static variables but would really like a hand as to how I could hook my program up together using methods.

Thanks a bunch,
M

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

You should do an object (class) decomposition.  First ask the question "What objects do I have".  (At a quick glance you might have "Text" and "Ticks" objects.  You then want to see what methods you want to use for each object.  For example in Text  have countTicks(Ticks).  Conotinue in this fashion to decompose your program.

Answer (score 0):

First, please indent your code more consistently, with the first line of a block three spaces farther to the right, such as

```
for(...)  {
   //Do stuff
   if(...)  {
      //Do stuff
   }
}
```

It is hard to read what you've posted (luckily someone spruced it up for you!).

Consider re-writing your program from scratch, instead of trying to fix what you already have. Your current knowledge of the problem should allow you to recreate it pretty quickly. You will probably be able to cut and paste bits and pieces from your original code as well.

How about starting small, with something like

```
Scanner sc = getInputScannerFromUserInput();

private static final Scanner getInputScannerFromUserInput()  {
   System.out.println("What file would you like to open?");
   return  new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

and just go from there. Bit by bit. Good luck!